# Custom x-axis for MATLAB graph

Tags: matlab, graph, line, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I want to have custom x-axis for a graph in MATLAB.

The values I want to plot in a line graph are:

```
A       B  
---------
1-10    5  
11-20   2
21-30   1
31-40   3
41-50   0
```

whereas, column A is x-axis and column B is y-axis.

I've tried the following:

```
x = 1:5;
y = [0 1 2 3 5]
plot(x, y, '-ob', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'blue')
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:5, 'XTickLabel',{"1-10" "11-20" "21-30" "31-40" "41-50"}
grid on
xlabel('Overlapping HEIs')
ylabel('Ranking-Intervals')
title('OpenRank-ARWU Overlapping')
```

The error is:

> `set(gca, 'XTick', 1:5, 'XTickLabel',{"1-10" "11-20" "21-30" "31-40" "41-50"}`
>    ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ↑
>   Error: Creating a string using double quotes is not supported.  Use the `string` function.

The output is:

[image: Output Graph]

Comment: I'm not getting how to insert `1-10` on x-axis

Comment: @SardarUsama I've provided what I tried

Comment: @SardarUsama is it right now? I guess I've provided each and every detail

Comment: @HunterJiang it's wrong, it showed 0 to 1 on x-axis

Comment: Yes, now your post is fine. Use `'` instead of `"`  (`"` is introduced in newer versions, you're probably using an older version) and there is a bracket missing `)` at the end of the line where you used `set`.

Comment: @SardarUsama it's alright. But the y-axis scale difference is 0.5 whereas I want to have a difference of 1

Comment: Set `YTick`s just like you set `XTick`  (you don't need to change `YTickLabel`s in this case and you're good to go

Comment: @SardarUsama When I used this `plot(x, y1, x, y2, '-s', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'blue','LineWidth',1.5)` it showed marker on y2 but not on y1

Comment: @SardarUsama I got it by using `plot(x, y1, '-s', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'blue', 'LineWidth',1.5)
hold on;
plot(x, y2, '-s', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'blue', 'LineWidth',1.5)
` Thanks